# id property returns null or undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the ID property hanging off the getElementById method however it seems to return null or undefined.  I have checked my HTML and it does in fact have an ID associated with it.  I have given all my columns different ID's so having mulitple occurrences of the same ID is not the problem.

```
var columnID = $(this).closest(".col-md-4.column").id;
console.log(columnID);
var column = document.getElementById(columnID);

 <div class="row" id="columns">
<div class="col-md-4 column" id="col1">
    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Panel title
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="testchart">
            CHART GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Panel title
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            World
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Panel title
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 column" id="col2">

</div>
<div class="col-md-4 column" id="col3">
```

Comment: try $(this).closest(".col-md-4.column").attr('id')

Comment: Hi @George worked like a charm put it as an answer to I can tick it?

Comment: one more way `var columnID = $(this).closest(".col-md-4.column").get(0).id;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var columnID = $(this).closest(".col-md-4.column").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `id` property.  Use `.attr('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).closest(".col-md-4.column").attr('id')
```

The attributes have to be accessed with the .attr method